# How to reduce font size for all images, dates and times in Microsoft MHT document?

Tags: html, regex

How to easily, non-programming, non-third-party way to reduce size of all:

1. dates and time
2. Images
3. Headers

Doing so helps those read essential information within MHT document from Steps Recorder.

As example, Windows Steps Recorder is showing

1. date and time
2. Title
3. Instructions

IMHO they are non-essential but taking too much footprint.
I have to use Word to process MHT document from Microsoft Steps Recorder
Can Word use regex?
[image: sample of non-essential text]

Answer (score 0):

For Microsoft Steps Recorder recorded file, my best workaround requires Word to find and replace with following criterion:

1. Bold Font
2. Wild card enabled
3. `\: \(*\)`

[How to de-emphasize Date and Time Information in saved HTML document by Microsoft Steps Recorder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEXV9.gif)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).